# Genexus and Ingres DBMS

Tags: jdbc, genexus, ingres

We're Actian Corp. partner reseller and have a customer that use Ingres DBMS for years. Now, they want to integrate Genexus developer environment with data store on an Ingres database. I was researching about data stores support for Genexus but apparently Ingres is not supported. However, Ingres has many open ways to connect to it, (JDBC, ODBC, Rubi, PHP). What I need to know is if there is some way to configure Genexus to have a new datastore pointing to an Ingres database using JDBC, ODBC, or whatever connection type.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Ingres is not supported by GeneXus.

You can, however, setup a DataStore and change the connection settings to ODBC, JDBC or whatever you want, and provide the connection information to the Ingres database.

There is a problem with this solution: the SQL syntax generated by GeneXus is different, depending on the chosen DBMS. So you would have to choose the most Ingres-like DMBS from the supported ones, to make sure it generates the SQL sentences correctly.

Comment: I expect that Genexus had the ability to connect to "other" datastore (different from those that it support natively), and then one could programming manually instead generated programs. Is this possible?

Comment: You can program manually if you want, but then you'll be missing all the benefits too.